# Unable to resolve com.google.android.exoplayer2 after Gradle update to v 5.4

Tags: android, gradle, exoplayer

My project is using com.google.android.exoplayer2. Until today I was at gradle 4.10.1 (android gradle plugin 3.3.1) - all fine. Once i updated to Gradle 5.4.1 exoplayer can not be resolved. Android Studio 3.4.

Module gradle (no change)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.2'
```

Project gradle (was 3.3.1)

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
```

Gradle wrapper properties (was 4.10.1)

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

stack trace logs 
http://vancura.cz/tmp/logs.log

Comment: add stacktrace logs

Comment: Have you tried Invalidate Caches and Restart and Clean Project?

Comment: Ronak Doshi - yes, no change

Comment: @NikunjParadva Paradva logs added

Answer (score 3):

My problem fixed by including individual exo dependencies in build.gradle file. In other words, If you just include

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.8'
```

the classes will not import. We should declare all components:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.11.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.11.8'
```

(In old exo versions (like r2.2.0) it was enough to simply include the main module)

Answer (score 0):

Change Exoplayer Dependencie

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.0'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.2'
```

> You need to make sure you have the Google and JCenter repositories included in the build.gradle file in the root of your project:

```
repositories {
  google()
  jcenter()
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have both repos in gradle, Changing exo version will at least resolve exoplayer, anyway I still have error : Android resource linking failed , android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found. resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Comment: upgrade your support libs also to latest version

Comment: go with this upgraded libs and change `compileSdkVersion 28` , your attr/fontVariationSetting error is gone try it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding bellow code in your workspace.xml

```
<component name="masterDetails">
    <states>
      <state key="ProjectJDKs.UI">
        <settings>
          <last-edited>1.8</last-edited>
          <splitter-proportions>
            <option name="proportions">
              <list>
                <option value="0.2" />
              </list>
            </option>
          </splitter-proportions>
        </settings>
      </state>
    </states>
  </component>
```

Comment: tested, still failing